# linux permission denied on owner files

Tags: linux, ssh, file-permissions, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have a colleague with a really weird problem.
We use a script that automatically put us in a working directory and then all files we create belong to a certain group that we are part of ( I don't know the code and I am not allowed to share it, but that's not the problem by the way). It has always worked well until 3 weeks ago. The problem is:
When creating a file, it's clear that the guy is the owner of the file and everyone (including him) who is part of the group can access to it. But if he then does a "`su`" to his own username and is no longer considered as member of the group, he can no longer access to his files even though he is still the owner (this is for every file located in the working directory). Even with a `chmod 777`. How is that even possible ?

(Other information: selinux seems disabled, we have the same environment variables set)

Added information:
Here is what `getfacl` do on a file of mine:

```
$ getfacl 01_EP_Tool_CB65RHS_Douglas.dat  
# file: 01_EP_Tool_CB65RHS_Douglas.dat  
# owner: my_username  
# group: gr-st_name  
user::rw-  
group::rw-  
other::---
```

Here is the same with the other file:

```
$ getfacl resultat_001.xls  
# file: resultat_001.xls  
# owner: other_username  
# group: gr-st_name  
user::rwx  
group::rwx  
other::---
```

Now `ls -ld`:

```
$ ll -ld 01_EP_Tool_CB65RHS_Douglas.dat  
-rw-rw---- 1 my_username gr-st_name 2957222 Jul 27 11:28 01_EP_Tool_CB65RHS_Douglas.dat

$ ls -ld resultat_001.xls  
-rwxrwx--- 1 other_username gr-st_name 3014 Jul 27 16:50 resultat_001.xls
```

Now upon connection, here is the result of `id` & `groups`:

```
$ id  
uid=47910(other_username) gid=147910(pgr-other_username) groups=1605(other_group8),2657(other_group9),2999(other_group1),3002(other_group2),3148(other_group3),3161(other_group4),3185(other_group5),3586(other_group6),3588(other_group7),3589(other_group10),3590(other_group11),3591(other_group12),3595(other_group1_d),3792(other_group13),3818(other_group14),3837(other_group14-2),3931(other_group13_s),**3972(gr-st_name)**,4007(other_group15),60419(other_group16),61055(other_group17),61115(other_group18),61123(other_group19),61127(other_group20),147910(pgr-other_username)

$ groups  
pgr-other_username other_group8 other_group9 other_group1 other_group2 other_group3 other_group4 other_group5 other_group6 other_group7 other_group10 other_group11 other_group12 other_group1_d other_group13 other_group14 other_group14-2 other_group13_s **gr-st_name** other_group15 other_group16 other_group17 other_group18 other_group19 other_group20
```

Then after entering the working environment:

```
$ id  
uid=47910(other_username) **gid=3972(gr-st_name)** groups=1605(other_group8),2657(other_group9),2999(other_group1),3002(other_group2),3148(other_group3),3161(other_group4),3185(other_group5),3586(other_group6),3588(other_group7),3589(other_group10),3590(other_group11),3591(other_group12),3595(other_group1_d),3792(other_group13),3818(other_group14),3837(other_group14-2),3931(other_group13_s),3972(gr-st_name),4007(other_group15),60419(other_group16),61055(other_group17),61115(other_group18),61123(other_group19),61127(other_group20),147910(pgr-other_username)

$ groups  
**gr-st_name** other_group8 other_group9 other_group1 other_group2 other_group3 other_group4 other_group5 other_group6 other_group7 other_group10 other_group11 other_group12 other_group1_d other_group13 other_group14 other_group14-2 other_group13_s other_group15 other_group16 other_group17 other_group18 other_group19 other_group20 pgr-other_username
```

Then, after `su other_username`:

```
$ id  
uid=47910(other_username) gid=147910(pgr-other_username) groups=1605(other_group8),2657(other_group9),2999(other_group1),3002(other_group2),3148(other_group3),3161(other_group4),3185(other_group5),3586(other_group6),3588(other_group7),3589(other_group10),3590(other_group11),3591(other_group12),3595(other_group1_d),3792(other_group13),3818(other_group14),3837(other_group14-2),3931(other_group13_s),**3972(gr-st_name)**,4007(other_group15),60419(other_group16),61055(other_group17),61115(other_group18),61123(other_group19),61127(other_group20),147910(pgr-other_username)

$ groups  
pgr-other_username other_group8 other_group9 other_group1 other_group2 other_group3 other_group4 other_group5 other_group6 other_group7 other_group10 other_group11 other_group12 other_group1_d other_group13 other_group14 other_group14-2 other_group13_s **gr-st_name** other_group15 other_group16 other_group17 other_group18 other_group19 other_group20
```

Concerning SELinux, he has:

```
$ cat /etc/selinux/config
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#       enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#       permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#       disabled - SELinux is fully disabled.
SELINUX=disabled
# SELINUXTYPE= type of policy in use. Possible values are:
#       targeted - Only targeted network daemons are protected.
#       strict - Full SELinux protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

As for why he does su with his own name, it's just a way to quit the group and stay at the same place.

Some new and possibly interesting information. Even though the user always uses the **other_username** login, there is another account that exists that also belongs to him: **yet_another_username**. If I do `finger` on them, both give the exact same information (as if they were kind of synchronised):

```
$ finger other_username
Login: other_username                          Name: some_email_address
Directory: /home/other_username                Shell: /bin/bash
On since Fri Jul 28 10:34 (CEST) on pts/36 from some_machine
    48 minutes 30 seconds idle
On since Fri Jul 28 09:36 (CEST) on pts/82 from some_other_machine
    19 minutes 49 seconds idle
On since Fri Jul 28 10:35 (CEST) on pts/150 from localhost:28.0
   47 minutes 53 seconds idle
On since Fri Jul 28 10:39 (CEST) on pts/170 from localhost:28.0
   44 minutes 25 seconds idle
     (messages off)
No mail.
No Plan.


$ finger yet_another_username
Login: other_username                          Name: some_email_address
Directory: /home/other_username                Shell: /bin/bash
On since Fri Jul 28 10:34 (CEST) on pts/36 from some_machine
    48 minutes 46 seconds idle
On since Fri Jul 28 09:36 (CEST) on pts/82 from some_other_machine
    20 minutes 5 seconds idle
On since Fri Jul 28 10:35 (CEST) on pts/150 from localhost:28.0
   48 minutes 9 seconds idle
On since Fri Jul 28 10:39 (CEST) on pts/170 from localhost:28.0
   44 minutes 41 seconds idle
     (messages off)
No mail.
No Plan.
```

Comment: Compare what `getfacl` reports for a "working" file with what it shows for a "broken" one.

Comment: Please show the output of `id` and `groups` before and after running `su`. (And why is he doing a `su` to his own username in the first place?) Also, just for good measure, show the output of `ls -l` (in addition to `getfacl`) on a file where he doesn’t have access (and one where he does, if there are any). In fact, please clarify — is the problem only with files *created* in the past three weeks, or has it affected *all* files (but just starting three weeks ago)?

Comment: I've added some information in my post. I'll add the rest in a couple hours.

Comment: See if turning off SELinux fixes the problem.  If it does, re-enable and fix the SELinux restrictions.

Comment: I think it's already disabled.     `$ cat /etc/selinux/config`
`# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#       enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#       permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#       disabled - SELinux is fully disabled.
SELINUX=disabled
# SELINUXTYPE= type of policy in use. Possible values are:
#       targeted - Only targeted network daemons are protected.
#       strict - Full SELinux protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a limit of 16 groups beyond which NFS can't tell if you are part of the group, and the group we were looking at was the 18th group hence the problem.

As we are not root on this system, we can't do things like `rpc.mountd -g` (seen here http://www.xkyle.com/solving-the-nfs-16-group-limit-problem/) or `usermod`.

So the not beautiful but pragmatic solution will be for us to use `newgrp` that we will put in the *.bashrc*